# Setting onClickListeners for buttons in scenes programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-4.4-kitkat, scene

I have 2 layouts which contain the same buttons

`layout_1.xml`

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        android:text="button2"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and 
`layout_2.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        android:text="button2"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Please assume these are all valid layouts etc.(I am just adding the relevant code.).

So in my fragment ,I inflate and use `layout_1.xml` in `onCreateView`.I want to toggle between the 2 scenes using `button_1`.
I can set the listener for `button_1` in `layout_1.xml` during the `onCreateView()`.
The problem is trying to set a listener on that button in the second view.i.e. the listener does not activate for the second scene(with `layout_2.xml`).And hence i canot toggle between the 2 scenes.Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What does your method look like for inflating the view upon button click?

Comment: Its just a scene transition, i.e.  `Scene.getSceneForLayout()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it is not a good idea to have multiple views with the same `id`. This is what caused the confusion here.

Note: Below is the solution used by OP that was suitable for their specific needs:

One simple solution is to use the `onClick` attribute in the XML file. You can assign the same onClick method to multiple items. Like this:

And in your activity.java add this:

```
public void buttonClicked(View v){

    Log.d("TAG","Button clicked!!"
    // do stuff here

}
```

---

*2nd option*:

When you set a listener for one button with the `id` of `button_1`, it does not set the `listener` for both buttons, it only sets it for the first one. If you  want to set the same `listener` for both, all you need to do is to assign these button different `ids` and then assign them the same `listener`.

This is what you should do:

```
Listener myListener = new Listener(){.. blah blah....};

((Button) findViewById(R.id.some_id)).setListerner(myListener);
((Button) findViewById(R.id.some_other_id)).setListerner(myListener);
```

---

*3rd option*:

```
findViewById(R.id.id_of_layout1).findViewById(R.id.button_1)
findViewById(R.id.id_of_layout2).findViewById(R.id.button_1)
```

in this case, you need add some id to your layout files, for example: layout_1.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="+id/id_of_layout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        android:text="button2"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I plan to use the fact that it is the same id to animate only certain objects in the scene.Hence the id was specified as same.Both the buttons do not exist during the same instance.And when a scene transition occurs,I needd to set listeners,so is theere a way to get the view from a current scene?

Comment: The xml method does not give me enough dynamicity(if that's a word).I need to add several listeners,hence I would prefer a programamtic approach.

Comment: yes but these are layout files,not inflated views.How do i get the inflated views so that i can call `findViewById()` ?

Comment: You cannot set listener for an not-yet-inflated view

Comment: But the thing is that when you use scenes,all tutorials show same ids for to indicate the same element being animated.check [here](http://developer.android.com/training/transitions/scenes.html)

Comment: I think the buttons should have differing id's like @Kasra mentioned, it makes sense for text views to have the same id because they are essentially the same, these 2 buttons are not

Comment: @JoeMaher If you maintain the same id,the animations provided to that object differ from the rest(it willl be translated instead of fading in etc etc).Hence the same ids are used.

Comment: @Kasra,I had to set it via xml to solve the problem.You have suggested all the answers possible here :).So please add that option as the solution finally used and I shall accept it :)

Comment: Awesome! Did you end up using onClick in XML?

Comment: Yes i did.And I am still surprised there si no programmatic way of dealing with this.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. This is incorrect as all shared element transitions should use the same ID

Answer (score 14):

It would actually appear that a proper way to do this would be to on the second scene you define an action to be performed as such:

```
mSecondScene.setEnterAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                 ((Button) mSecondScene.getSceneRoot().findViewById(R.id. button_1)).setOnClickListener( ... );
    }
```

This will allow you to set your ClickListener on the View without the data binding to a generic click listener method. Then you can perform the Transition to the second scene and viola.

Comment: You're a godsent. Been looking for this damn solution for ages! "How to bind data into a newly loaded scene." Seems no ones using Scenes so there isn't much info on this! Androids Scene documentation should be updated. Thank you!